# Suggestions for java obfuscator to change method/class/variable names

Tags: java, obfuscation

I' looking for a java obfuscator that will at a minimum rename all private method names, inner method variables such that reading the source code and decompiling a jar will make it unfriendly to do so.

I realize it isn't that hard to get algorithm knowledge etc., I just want it to be a pain to decompile and thus maintain the decompiled code.

The goal is to prevent someone from decompiling the source and simply using it w/o having to do any work.  I don't care if they can figure out my algorithms etc., I just don't want it to be super easy where they can just decompile the .jar and add the 100% visible and readable source code into their project.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

ProGuard is what I use.

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

has a nice easy to use GUI or can be implemented into ant scripts. Also offers optimization and some other nice features.

Answer (score 2):

Obfuscation is not your only option. See my article "[Protect Your Java Code - Through Obfuscators and Beyond](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html)". If nothing else, you will find there links to actively maintained obfuscators.